# Conservative vector fields in Minkowski Space?

Tags: special-relativity, conservative-field

Is there an analog to a conservative vector field in Minkowski Space?  If so, under what conditions are fields "conservative in Minkowski Space"?

Comment: Why would the notion of conservativity depend on the metric? The notion of derivative doesn't change between Euclidean and Minkowski space, so "is the derivative of a potential" still works perfectly fine. I'm therefore not sure why you think we need an analog instead of just using the exact same notion.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the fact that the space and time components in the four/Minkowski gradient had opposite signs meant that some theorems about potential functions and line integrals wouldn't apply.  Also, I was wondering if curly electric and magnetic fields, made curly as a result of  time varying magnetic or electric fields, could be expressed as the four gradient of a (possibly complex?) scaler potential.

Comment: For some reason, I thought the reason curly electric or magnetic fields are not conservative had something to do with the fact that energy and momentum in the fields are being exchanged between electric and magnetic components, and that the opposite signs of the space and time components of the four gradient would in four dimensions create some way around the fact that a curly field coupled to another curly field cannot be expressed as the gradient of a scaler in Euclidean 3 space; also might a scalar potential as a function of space and time coordinates contain information about both fields?